# Count occurrences of value in field for a particular ID using Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to count the occurrences of particular values in a certain field for an ID.  So what I have is this:

```
| Location ID |   Group  |
|:----------- |:---------|
| 1           |  Group A |      
| 2           |  Group B |      
| 3           |  Group C |   
| 4           |  Group A |  
| 4           |  Group B | 
| 4           |  Group C | 
| 3           |  Group A | 
| 2           |  Group B | 
| 1           |  Group C |    
| 2           |  Group A |
```

And what I would hope to yield through some computer magic is this:

```
| Location ID | Group A Count | Group B Count | Group C count|
|:----------- |:--------------|:--------------|:-------------|
| 1           | 1             | 0             | 1            |
| 2           | 1             | 2             | 0            |
| 3           | 1             | 0             | 1            |
| 4           | 1             | 1             | 1            |
```

Is there some sort of pivoting function I can use in Redshift to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will require the usage of the CASE function and GROUP clause, as in example.

```
SELECT l_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN l_group = 'Group A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a,
       SUM(CASE WHEN l_group = 'Group B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b-- and so on
       FROM location
GROUP BY l_id;
```

This should give you such result:

```
| l_id | a | b |
|------|---|---|
|    4 | 1 | 1 |
|    1 | 1 | 0 |
|    3 | 1 | 0 |
|    2 | 1 | 2 |
```

You can play with it on this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5ea62/6).